# jQuery: skipping first table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the HTML:

```
<table id="tblTestAttributes">
    <thead>
        <tr> <th>Head 1</th> <th>Head 2</th> </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr> <td id="txtDesc">Item 1</td> <td id="ddlFreq">Assume a DropDownList Here</td> </tr>
        <tr> <td id="txtDesc">Item 1</td> <td id="ddlFreq">Assume a DropDownList Here</td> </tr>
        <tr> <td id="txtDesc">Item 1</td> <td id="ddlFreq">Assume a DropDownList Here</td> </tr>
    </tbody>            
</table>
```

This is the javascript to get the values of each row:

```
var frequencies = [];
if ($('#tblTestAttributes').length) {
    $('#tblTestAttributes tr').each(function () {
        var t = $(this).find('td[id^="txtDesc"]').text() + ";" + $(this).find('[id^="ddlFreq"] option:selected').val();
        alert(t);
        frequencies.push(t);
    });
}
```

I want to avoid the first row, which contains `th` elements which are just display headers and don't contain any data.

So I changed the selector to this:

```
#tblTestAttributes tr:not(:first-child)
```

This is skipping the second `tr` as well. What is happening here?

Comment: An ID has to be unique. Use classes instead.

Comment: Edited to include thead and tbody in the HTML snippet.

Comment: You are right about using ID's and not Classes. I didn't even notice it until you mentioned. Again the HTML (in our project) is completely in UI designer's hands, so I need to push this change to them. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of performance, using `.find()` will be better than resolving the selector with Sizzle.

```
$('#tblTestAttributes').find('tbody').find('tr').each(function () { ... });
```

Here's the **[jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/find-vs-sizzle-for-table-row-loop)** to show it.

Comment: Thanks for showing me the chaining. I didn't see your answer until I accepted the answer.

Comment: Can you explain what is sizzle is in this context? I am asking this as I have only jumped into a sea of jQuery since three weeks and learning things as I go.

Comment: When you write $(...).someFunction() you're passing some elements to a function. To get the elements, you can you use the internal sizzle engine (which is what the other answers do) or you can get the top-level element with $('#elementID'), for which there's nothing to resolve since it's an ID, and then use .find() to filter what you need, in this case the first row but not the header. You should change the accepted answer.

Comment: If you're working for desktop only then performance may not matter much but for mobile, you should think performance. Besides, if you keep the habit of using sizzle selectors, you're eventually going to have some very complex ones that can stall the page, especially if there's ajax involved.

Comment: Thank you for taking time for explaining what sizzle is.

Comment: No problem. In fact, just realized that your internal function is also using sizzle. This is how I would rewrite those, assuming you've corrected your HTML to using classes instead of IDs in the rows: var t = $(this).find('.txtDesc').text() + ";" + $(this).find('.ddlFreq').val(); Also, if you're using a .each() loop and you're doing $(this) a lot inside the loop then the first line of the loop should be var This = $(this); to cache the value of $(this) and then you'd use var t = This.find... Here you're using $(this) only twice so there's no need to cache it but just keep that in mind.

Answer (score 7):

Simple you can use below code

```
$('#tblTestAttributes tr:not(:has(th))').each(function () {
```

Comment: This is the most elegant solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
#tblTestAttributes tr:gt(0)
```

or

```
#tblTestAttributes tbody tr
```

I would recommend the 2nd, because it may take advantage of querySelectorAll and should be the fastes solution.

your approach didn't work as expected, because the 2nd `tr` is also a `first-child`(of `tbody`)

Answer (score 2):

Use `tr + tr` selector, which gets all `tr` that appear after another `tr`, so the first one is skipped.

Also no need to check if table exists, as in that case `$.each` wouldn't even get executed.

```
var frequencies = [];
    $('#tblTestAttributes tr + tr').each(function () {
        var t = $(this).find('td[id^="txtDesc"]').text() + ";" + $(this).find('[id^="ddlFreq"] option:selected').val();
        alert(t);
        frequencies.push(t);
    });
```

**After your edit:**

Simply select only all `tr` inside `tbody`:

```
$('#tblTestAttributes tbody tr').each(function(){
    ...
}
```

Comment: You have changed the `html`, it's a completely different question now :).

Comment: Hey, sorry about that. I was under the impression that I am operating on the TRs, so thead and tbody should not matter, but later felt like I should make the question more clear.

Comment: This is a slow option: http://jsperf.com/find-vs-sizzle-for-table-row-loop Take a look at my answer for performance.

Comment: There is no "slow" in javascript unless you're talking about hundread of thousand of elements/operations, which I really doubt is the case :).

Comment: @frenchie: If performance was truly an issue, then the first thing to do would be to drop jQuery and go native. http://jsperf.com/find-vs-sizzle-for-table-row-loop/2 Your answer and Cristy's are remarkably similar in performance in comparison. The difference between yours and native is *enormous*.

Comment: Wow, indeed. I just wanted to optimize the selector but indeed, going native is much much faster than using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the second row is, in fact, the first child of the `tbody` just like the first row is the first child of the `thead`.

To only take the elements you need, I'd suggest something nearer from your need :

```
#tblTestAttributes tr:has(td)
```

Don't forget to get rid of those duplicate `txtDesc` id, this is illegal in HTML, use a class instead.